# Accessing different JSON key/value pairs in a list comprehension

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

Not sure if i am trying to achieve the impossible? I have this JSON string:

```
dot= [{"type": 1, "date": "2018-12-02T00:40:03.2186792+00:00", "device": 
[{"id": "20165cf4e596", "deviceName": "17", "records": [{"timestamp": "2018- 
12-02T00:40:00.499+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 887}]}, {"id": 
"5f401a6a6f66", "deviceName": "18", "records": [{"timestamp": "2018-12- 
02T00:42:00.499+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 1063}, {"timestamp": 
"2018-12-02T00:41:00.498+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 907}]}, {"id": 
"569bb0147a72", "deviceName": "19", "records": [{"timestamp": "2018-12- 
02T00:44:00.499+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 817}, {"timestamp": 
"2018-12-02T00:43:00.498+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 1383}]}, {"id": 
"ef829aa3", "deviceName": "2", "records": [{"timestamp": "2018-12- 
02T00:46:00.499+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 1173}]}, {"id": 
"388ae8f2fa64", "deviceName": "17", "records": [{"timestamp": "2018-12- 
02T00:41:00.499+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 866}, {"timestamp": 
"2018-12-02T00:32:00.492+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 1080}]}, {"id": 
"01f874b30b55", "deviceName": "19", "records": [{"timestamp": "2018-12- 
02T00:43:00.499+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 1050}, {"timestamp": 
"2018-12-02T00:42:00.498+00:00", "grp": "undefined", "val": 1084}]}]}]
```

And i want to achieve the following:

```
[{'id': '20165cf4e596','deviceName': '17','timestamp': '2018-12- 
02T00:40:00.499+00:00','grp': 'undefined','val': 887},
{'id': '5f401a6a6f66','deviceName': '18','timestamp': '2018-12- 
02T00:42:00.499+00:00','grp': 'undefined','val': 1063},
{'id': '5f401a6a6f66','deviceName': '18','timestamp': '2018-12- 
02T00:41:00.498+00:00','grp': 'undefined','val': 907},...]
```

I used the following code:

```
for i in dot:
    for k in i['device']:
        d2= [[{l:m},{'value':v}] for l,m in k.items() for p in m if 
        isinstance(p,list) for v in p]
        print(d2)
```

And got empty lists:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check why `if 
    isinstance(p,list)` is always false; possibly by unrolling your comprehension into classical loops

Comment: also: your input data has linefeeds in the strings, so noone can copy/paste as-is to test. Please correct this.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre not sure what you mean. It appears it has been resolved though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the `records` element of each device. Then combine the fields from the device with each record.

```
result = []
for i in dot:
    for k in i['device']:
        for r in k['records']:
            result.append({"id": k["id"], "deviceName": k["deviceName"], "timestamp": r["timestamp"], "grp": r["grp"], "val": r["val"]})
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar it worked a treat. I was looking at something too complex. Thanks for simplifying. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53839391/3474146) may be correct - but I believe you will have a far easier time if you deobfuscate your code by creating a hierarchy of objects which represent items in your data structure:

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self, some_object_type, date, devices):
        self.type = some_object_type
        self.date = date
        self.devices = []

        for d in devices:
            some_device = SomeDevice(d["id"], d["deviceName"], d["records"])
            self.devices.append(some_device)

class SomeDevice:
    def __init__(self, some_device_id, name, records):
        self.id = some_device_id
        self.name = name
        self.records = []

        for r in records:
            some_record = SomeDeviceRecord(r["timestamp"], r["grp"], r["val"])
            self.records.append(some_record)

class SomeDeviceRecord:
    def __init__(self, timestamp, group, value):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.group = group
        self.value = value
```

If you go this route, you can easily parse the entire JSON into strongly-typed objects:

```
some_object = SomeObject(dot[0]["type"], dot[0]["date"], dot[0]["device"])
```

And then it should be fairly easy/straightforward to report on specific portions of the data structure:

```
for device in some_object.devices:
    print(device.id, device.name, device.records[0].timestamp, device.records[0].group, device.records[0].value)
```

Comment: Thanks @alex, yes agreed, this gives complete control over all elements of the JSON. I added '{}' to group related values. Is there a way i can sort the values, so i can convert to a DataFrame? [{'17', '20165cf4e596', '2018-12-02T00:40:00.499+00:00', 887, 'undefined'},
 {1063, '18', '2018-12-02T00:42:00.499+00:00', '5f401a6a6f66', 'undefined'},
 {'19', '2018-12-02T00:44:00.499+00:00', '569bb0147a72', 817, 'undefined'}]

Comment: Yes.  I don't know offhand but you can probably use `sorted()` with lambdas on `some_object.devices`.

Comment: Thanks @alex, will definitely give this a go. Much appreciated!

Comment: I assumed the eventual goal was to turn it into something like a CSV, which was the point of flattening everything.

Comment: @Barmar Entirely reasonable :)